# Cannot choose windows in GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

I have installed edubuntu 13.04 in one of my computers. Now I am unable to select or rather even move the selection in the GRUB during boot time. So Ubuntu is automatically loaded. I am unable to get into Windows 8.
   I tried boot repair once and got a link http://paste.ubuntu.com/7129807/ which I couldn't comprehend. What can I do to be able to access Windows 8? Help Required.

Comment: Is the grub menu showing or is it instantly booting into ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly look at the position of Windows8 in GRUB menu,
ie if Windows8 is at 5th position then consider it as an array and consider its position as 4.

In order to load Windows 8 on default just edit grub.cfg by typing in,

*sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg*

in the terminal, find for the line default=0 in grub.cfg and change the value to your previously noted value (In this case 4)

NOW ITS IMPORTANT TO UPDATE THE SETTINGS BY TYPING IN,

*sudo update-grub*

Alternatively you could also install GRUB customizer,

*sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer*

Answer (score 0):

I found this guy requesting for help to solve a boot problem that looks like yours: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515153

^They couldn't solve the problem, but they came up with a temporary solution: "I went ahead and burned a copy of supergrub boot disk to CD and am able to boot to all my partitions"
Try to download and run Super Grub2 Disk for now.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. As your answer may be helpful but - as you said yourself - it doesn't really solve the problem. As such it would be better to just write a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the advice, but I don't think I can comment other people with my current "reputation".